# Does "El Buscado" make sense as a lottery card?

Tags: traducción, modismos, méxico

I am designing some variations on lottery cards, and I need one that means "The Wanted" (like an outlaw).  Would "El Buscado" be understood and sound correct to a Spanish speaker?  "El Hombre Buscado" seems like too many words because the lottery cards are all two word titles.

I could go with "El Forajido" but it would be better if it really meant "The Wanted."

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Se busca" Sería la traducción correcta para "wanted" pero teniendo en cuenta que se trata de una lotería "El buscado" suena bien para mi.

Comment: Since all the loteria cards are "el *" or "la *" I think keeping the format consistent is best, so this is what I was hoping to hear. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The "Wanted" phrase from Western movies is usually translated as "Se busca".

Would "Se busca" work as a lottery card? It is a matter of taste, but I think it sounds quite nice.

And the jackpot could be "Wanted dead or alive", that is "Se busca vivo o muerto". Too many words?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is too late, but I would suggest "El perseguido", like in "perseguido por la justicia". You can also use it as a wordplay with "perseguir el premio".